# Backlight not on during Ubuntu 11.10 Installation HP Folio 13

Tags: hp, backlight

I have a HP Folio 13 B2A32UT and I am trying to install Ubuntu 11.10 64bit,

But unfortunately after it shows the purple screen, with the little human and the keyboard in the bottom of the screen and when it gets to the point to show the window with the 2 buttons which say:

"Install Ubuntu","Try Ubuntu"

It shows almost nothing to the screen as it is like the back-light of the screen is turned off!

The problem is that I am not able to see anything as it is next to impossible to see what the screen shows and the only way to see what the screen displays at this moment is to put a lamplight very close to the screen. But,again everything that is displayed looks very dim and I can't do the installation properly. Can anybody help?

Comment: The weird thing is that I already tried that,but nothing happened!o_O

Comment: okay,but how do i open a terminal without having installed the os?

Comment: Okay guys.Thanks for your answers.I tried what you told,but I haven't managed to solve it.So I tried to install 10.04 LTS and you know what.....It worked like a charm!!!Anyways,thank you all for your answers again.

Answer (score 4):

Press shift key when you see the little human and keyboard icon. Then choose your keyboard and press f6 then esc. You should see a text line. Add to this line "acpi_backlight=vendor" then run the install or try.

Remember that you must add in the grub file "acpi_backlight=vendor" when you restart your computer at the end of the install.

For more details go to : http://labo.eliaz.fr/spip.php?article94

Comment: I had to hit fn-F6, because I think the F6 key is mapped to a media key by default, and you have to use the fn key to use normal F-keys.

Answer (score 0):

I've a solution, When this problem occured to my hp laptop, I just turn on emergency light (or torch) infront of LCD, then every thing was visible, then I go to ubuntu system settings , in the brightness option, I just increased the brightness seekbar, then My LCD backlight worked, and every problem was solved, then save this setting